# Restart powershell script

Tags: windows-10, powershell, script

My script counts the audio files on the PC and checks if the drive entered in the input is the system drive. If it is, a message is sent to Return or Exit the script. I created the :INI and :EXIT paragraphs, but the script does not return to :INI?

Script:

```
clear-Host
:INI
cls
Write-Host "                                          Count Audio Files on PC" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$br
$local= Read-Host -Prompt " Enter your path Music folder. Eg. D:\*"
$location = "$local"

$locTst = $location.substring(0,2)

# Check if the drive c:
If ($locTst -eq "c:") {
    write-host -ForegroundColor Red " Drive $locTst does not allow access to external scripts!"
    $dirLoc= Read-Host -Prompt " Return?(Y/N)"
    if ($dirLoc -eq "y") { 
       :INI
    } else {  
       :EXIT
    }
}

commands to counting audio files...

:EXIT
exit
```

How to make the script return to :INI to restart the script and also in :EXIT the powershell screen is closed?

I tried to use the commands from this link, but they give an error in Powershell ISE and I couldn't debug the code.
[how can i allow y/n to be input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65454348/how-can-i-allow-only-y-n-to-be-input-in-read-host-without-having-to-press-enter)

Comment: why do you expect **_BASIC/bat/cmd_** `goto` style commands to work in Powershell? [*grin*] use standard loop structures instead of BASIC `goto` style commands. something like the `While` structure >>> `Get-Help about_While`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In keeping with your current PowerShell coding constructs, give this slight modification a try:

```
clear-Host
while ($true) {
    cls
    Write-Host "                                          Count Audio Files on PC" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $br
    $local= Read-Host -Prompt " Enter your path Music folder. Eg. D:\*"
    $location = "$local"

    $locTst = $location.substring(0,2)

    # Check if the drive c:
    If ($locTst -eq "c:") {
         write-host -ForegroundColor Red " Drive $locTst does not allow access to external scripts!"
         $dirLoc= Read-Host -Prompt " Return?(Y/N)"
         if ($dirLoc -eq "y") { 
             continue
         } else {  
             break
         }
    }

    # commands to counting audio files...
    break
}

exit
```

This uses a `while` loop to `continue` keeping users inside your INI section, so long as they respond with "y" for drive C: content; and will `break` out of the loop (and `exit`) if not.

Comment: worked. Is there a way to not need to press ENTER after choosing between Y/N? eg. after pressing y, it already executes the command.

Comment: Use `$dirLoc = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey()`, then check `if ('y' -eq $dirLoc.Character)`

Comment: that worked too, thanks!